# If $A$ and $B$ are two events and is $S$ is the sample space, does $\overline{(A \cap B)} \cup A = S$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are two events and is $S$ is the sample space, does $\overline{(A \cap B)} \cup A = S$?

I get that $\overline{(A \cap B)} \cup A  =  (\overline {A} \cup \overline{B}) \cup A = \overline{A} \cup  (\overline{B} \cup A) = \overline{A} \cup A = S?$ Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is right.

But your argument looks like you're assuming that $\overline B\cup A=A$, which would not necessarily hold. Instead you can say
$$ \overline A \cup \overline B \cup A = (\overline A \cup A)\cup \overline B = S \cup \overline B = S $$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise I could use associativity like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct .

Please edit the title so it matches your proof.